# Drupal Gmap Views - Popups are too big

Tags: javascript, drupal, google-maps, view

I'm using GMAP module and its views counterpart.  The issue I'm having, is I'm using a custom text field to display fields wrapped in html that I have pulled in from the query.  However, the popup, won't size correctly, it ends up being too big.  Here's my code for Custom Text Field:

```
<div id="col1">
[field_thtr_img_fid]
</div>
<div id="col2">
<h5>[title]</h5>
[address_1]
</div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Crap - I'm such a jerk - always forget to do that.  Thanks for the kick in the ass :)  Will go do some accepts now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wrap the whole chunk in a div with a class then you can target that class with a width.

e.g.

```
<div class='foo'>
  .. YOUR HTML ..
</div>
```

And add this css to your page:

```
.foo {
  width: 75px;
}
```

That works for me.